# How to dynamicaly populate a table depending on the users selection in dropdown list

Tags: javascript, php, database

[image]

I made an employee DTR (shown in the picture) that displays employees DTR. I want to put dropdown list above the table. The dropdown list would be period. For example I chose March 01-16 2018, so the table will only display that period.

Comment: here is my complete databse and php programs https://drive.google.com/file/d/14ztI7JeQ2Hu2-PvJF9aw108ZX3DSZg5A/view?usp=sharing

Comment: i had done several tries formulating the dropdown and auto change the table data but it did not work i hope someone can help me

Comment: i have uploaded the whole system on the given link thank you for the hint

Answer (score 0):

i don't know what code you have written so far to implement this type of functionality.
so, as per your requirement you can try this thing :[Data Tables For PHP](https://datatables.net/examples/data_sources/server_side)

Comment: i will try to implement this to my system thank you for the link. ill get back if ill make any progress